# If clone() value is made zero the original object value also changes to zero

Tags: java, clone

I am making a copy of my object by using clone() method. But when there is modification in the copy the original object is also modified. I have tried to replicate my issue in the following example. Here are 2 classes ClassA and ClassB.

```
public class ClassB implements Cloneable
{
    int num = 0;

    byte[] bit = new byte[1];

     //Getters and setters have been removed due to space constraint

            public Object clone() 
    {
        try
        {   
          ClassB obj = (ClassB)super.clone();

          obj.setNum(this.num);
               obj.setBit(this.bit);

          return obj;
        } catch (CloneNotSupportedException e) {
                return null;              }
    }
}
```

//Here is ClassA whioch contains the main method and uses clone

```
public class ClassA {

    public void cloneMethod(){

        ClassB objB = new ClassB();
        objB.bit[0] = (byte)0x8;
        objB.setNum(5);     

        ClassB objCopy = null;
        objCopy = (ClassB) objB.clone();

        if(objCopy.bit[0] != (byte)0x0)
        {
            objCopy.bit[0] = 0;
        }

        System.out.println(objB.bit[0]); //At this point the original object    value is also modified.

    }

    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        ClassA a = new ClassA();
        a.cloneMethod();
    }

}
```

Now how to retain the original object value? I know clone has certain disadvantages. I have tried with new key word also but it doesnt help.Please suggest.
in my original code I have to use the original object bit value later for some more calculation and the copy object bit value will be 0.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't set `bit` to the same `byte[]` as the original object, instead clone it as well:

```
obj.bit = this.bit.clone();
```

Also, you don't need to set `num`, because that will already be set correctly on the object returned by `super.clone()`.

Comment: @JavaBits: This is exactly what you need, a [deep copy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deep_copy#Deep_copy)!

Comment: Yes I just found out the same. Thanks a lot. It is working perfectly.

Comment: IMHO, the most useful semantics for a "clone" method, especially for a generic class, shouldn't be a deep copy, but rather what I'd call a "semantic level" copy.  A clone of a FooCollection<T> should be a new FooCollection<T> which holds the same T's as the originals; mutations performed on the original FooCollection should not affect the clone, but mutations performed on the T's in the original collection therein should affect the T's seen in the clone (since they should be the same T's).  Basically, the behavior of the cloned FooCollection should not depend upon how...

Comment: ...the FooCollection itself stores things (whether it uses an array, nested arrays, a linked list, or whatever), but instead FooCollection should behave as though it is a single block which holds independent T's.  I don't know of any particular term to describe such semantics; if I had my druthers, that style of clone would be a "shallow copy", while anything shallower would be called a "broken copy", but since the term "shallow copy" is often used for what I'd call a "broken copy", I'm not sure what the best term would be.

Answer (score 1):

```
obj.setNum(this.num);
obj.setBit(this.bit);
```

These two lines of code are (a) redundant and (b) wrong. If you just want the original field values in the clone you don't need this at all, because super.clone() has already done it for you. If your aim is to return an independently-valued object. As bit[] is an array, i.e. an Object, you should clone it too.

Answer (score 0):

You are not cloning your `bit` array.